# Is it possible to avoid inheritance by using std::variant?

Tags: c++

I was trying to see if I can rewrite the following code without using inheritance:

```
struct X {};
struct A : X {};
struct B : X {};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<X> xptr = std::make_unique<A>();
}
```

I tried rewriting it using std::variant so that I can make use of std::holds_alternative and std::get instead of using dynamic_cast:

```
struct A;
struct B;
using X = std::variant<A, B>;
struct A {};
struct B {};

int main() {
    X x = A();                                        // works
    std::unique_ptr<X> xptr = std::make_unique<A>();  // doesn't work
}
```

But I'm getting the error: no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr' to 'unique_ptr' when I try to compile the code above.

Is there a way to make the above code work, or is there another way to avoid using dynamic_cast?

Comment: These two snippets do two completely different things. It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - can you explain your original problem?

Comment: You might be interested in the following 2 posts: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/ https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/type-erasure-part-ii/

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to store a `std::unique_ptr<A>` in a `std::unique_ptr<std::variant<A,B> >`????

Comment: You can rewrite the code to do absolutely anything, but without your requirements & constraints we couldn't possibly guarantee giving you a _useful_ suggestion. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: The question is, *why* avoid inheritance if you actually need it?

Answer (score 3):

Type `X` and type `A` are totally disjoint, so pointer (smart or not) on `A` cannot be assigned to pointer on `X`.

May be should you try this?

```
std::unique_ptr<X> xptr = std::make_unique<X>(A{});
```

Comment: Actually, depending on the class, using `std::in_place_type_t<A>` might be more efficient, as it'll avoid making a redundant copy.